# Why can I remove user from many to many relation in django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I am unable to remove a current user from a many-to-many relation in Django

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    content=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    owner=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liked_by=models.ManyToManyField(User,symmetrical=False,related_name="liked_by",blank=True)
```

Given above are my models

```py
def like(request,id):
    x=Post.objects.get(id=id)
    x.liked_by.add(request.user)
    x.save()
    return JsonResponse({"status":"successfully liked"})

def unlike(request,id):
   if request.method=="GET":
        x=Post.objects.get(id=id)
        x.liked_by.remove(request.user)
        x.save()
        return JsonResponse({"status":"successfully unliked"})
```

the above functions are used to like and unlike a post. I am able to like i.e. add a user to the many-to-many relation but I'm unable to remove it.

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
{%for post in posts%}
    <div>{{post.content}} 
       
            
    
        
        <button class="like" value="{{post.id}}">{%if request.user in post.liked_by.all%}unlike{%else%}like{%endif%}</button>
        
    </div>
{%endfor%}
<script>
    let like=document.querySelectorAll('.like')
    
    like.forEach(Element=>{
        Element.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
            const clickedbutton=event.target
            if(clickedbutton.innerHTML==='like'){
                fetch('like/'+clickedbutton.value)
                clickedbutton.innerHTML='unlike'
            }
            else if(clickedbutton.innerHTML==='unlike'){
                fetch('unlike/'+clickedbutton.value)
                clickedbutton.innerHTML='like'
            }
            
        })
    })
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

this is the html I tried. My objective is to remove a current user for many-to-many relation upon clicking `unlike`.